# Big-O Notation as a hull operator?

Tags: asymptotics, convex-hulls

I have to prove the following:

> Let $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}.$
>
> Define:
> $ {  \mathcal{O} (F) = \{ g : \mathbb{N}}\rightarrow
> > \mathbb{R}| \exists f \in F\exists C>0\exists n_0 \in\mathbb{N}\forall
> > n \in \mathbb{N}(n \geq n_0 \rightarrow |g(n)| \le C|f(n)| \}$
>
> Prove if $\mathcal{O} : {2^\mathbb{R}}^\mathbb{N}  \rightarrow {2^\mathbb{R}}^\mathbb{N} $ is a hull operator. What is his Universe $U$?

I don't know what to show exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am not really sure what Universe means in this context, but to see whether $\mathcal{O}$ is a hull operatoe, you need to check three properties: (i) $F\subseteq \mathcal{O}(F)$; (ii) $F\subseteq G\implies \mathcal{O}(F)\subseteq \mathcal{O}(F)$; (iii) $\mathcal{O}(F)=\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{O}(F))$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Thanks for your advise! I‘ve proven those three properties. True... I‘m not sure what he meant by „Universe“ in this context.